# Woocommerce y product archive

Tags: woocommerce

tengo una web en Woocommerce  y cuando monto una categoría de mis productos como "cristal" y voy a sus productos por defecto, la página de produce archive me muestra su texto de descripción pero no los productos. He probado de todo, tanto desactivar plugins, temas, codigo fuente pero nada también cambié las típicas opciones por defecto de product Woocommerce  pero tampoco.